# Getting ! Dimension Too large when knitting a rmarkdown file to a pdf

Tags: fancybox

I am receiving the following error when trying to knit my rmarkdown file to a `pdf`:

> ! Dimension too large. \fb@put@frame ...p \ifdim \dimen@ >\ht
> @tempboxa
> \fb@putboxa #1\fb@afterfra... l.4878 \end{Shaded}
>
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile Final_Exam_Part2.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> Final_Exam_Part2.log for more info. In addition: There were 50 or more
> warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50) Execution halted

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.